# How to add names to images on tab bar swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to add names bellow the sf symbols, like home, menu, add new:

[image]

Like in this picture:

[image]

This is the code, using a vm machine and cant copy the code:

[image]

Comment: You need to provide enough to let us help you, which will usually involve testing a solution which will need actual code.  If you can't be bothered to put the actual code into the question very few will bother to transpose it to help you.

Comment: The actual code is in the photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this but that is not a tab bar, here is an example on how you can do it your way, basically you would add another array with the names for the tabs and wrap the Image and the Text into a `VStack`:

```
let tabNames = ["Profile", "Settings", etc...]

HStack {
    ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { number in
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            self.selectedIndex = number
        }, label: {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: icons[number])
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedIndex == number ? .black : Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                Text(tabNames[number])
                font(.system(size: 25, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedIndex == number ? .black : Color(UIColor.lightGray))
            }
        })
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
Isnt his way easier than the normal tab bar?
Is this affecting performance or something like that?

Comment: It very much depends on how you are structuring your code around this. It shouldn't affect performance as long as you keep your code well organized. It's nothing wrong with this approach but i suggest you use this approach only if a TabView is not suitable for your use case. If this  answer has been helpful you can mark it as seleted.